# UnicodeDecodeError When I use cuda to train dataset

Tags: python, chainer, cupy

I used chainer to train some images but there is an error.

I don't know whether its  UnicodeDecodeError or the error of installation of cupy.

```
P:\dcgans\chainer-DCGAN\chainer-DCGAN>python DCGAN.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DCGAN.py", line 279, in <module>
    train_dcgan_labeled(gen, dis)
  File "DCGAN.py", line 171, in train_dcgan_labeled
    zvis = (xp.random.uniform(-1, 1, (100, nz), dtype=np.float32))
  File "P:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cupy\random\distributions.py", line 132, in uniform
    return rs.uniform(low, high, size=size, dtype=dtype)
  File "P:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cupy\random\generator.py", line 235, in uniform
    rand = self.random_sample(size=size, dtype=dtype)
  File "P:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cupy\random\generator.py", line 153, in random_sample
    RandomState._1m_kernel(out)
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 552, in cupy.core.core.ElementwiseKernel.__call__ (cupy\core\core.cpp:43810)
  File "cupy/util.pyx", line 39, in cupy.util.memoize.decorator.ret (cupy\util.cpp:1480)
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 409, in cupy.core.core._get_elementwise_kernel (cupy\core\core.cpp:42156)
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 12, in cupy.core.core._get_simple_elementwise_kernel (cupy\core\core.cpp:34787)
  File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 32, in cupy.core.core._get_simple_elementwise_kernel (cupy\core\core.cpp:34609)
  File "cupy/core/carray.pxi", line 87, in cupy.core.core.compile_with_cache (cupy\core\core.cpp:34264)
  File "P:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 133, in compile_with_cache
    base = _empty_file_preprocess_cache[env] = preprocess('', options)
  File "P:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 99, in preprocess
    pp_src = pp_src.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 27-28: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Which version of CuPy/Chainer are you using?

Comment: @niboshi  chainer (2.0.2) cupy (1.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `nvcc` generated non-UTF8 output and CuPy failed to decode it.
This is a bug of CuPy (I posted an issue: [#378](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/378)).

A possible solution for the time being is to replace `'utf-8'` in `cupy/cuda/compiler.py` at the line `pp_src = pp_src.decode('utf-8')` with something that match your environment. For example, in Japanese environment, `'cp932'` should work, and `'cp936'` should perhaps work for simplified Chinese.

You could also try `locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]` as a universal solution (be sure to `import locale`).

**Update**: The fix has been merged. It should be fixed in upcoming CuPy v1.0.3.